# 2DPooling in Keras doesn't pool last column

Tags: keras

When performing 2DPooling in keras over an input with odd dimension, say 8x24x128, the output is appropriately 4x12x128 if 2x2 pooling is used. When the input has an odd dimension, say 8x25x128, the output is 4x12x128. The pooling does NOT operate on the last column (25) of the input. I would like to zero pad the input to 8x26x128 with an extraneous zero column. Is this possible?

In general terms: what is the proper etiquette for pooling over odd dimensional inputs?

Comment: How would keras pool a single column ? The operation consists in taking the mean or max of two columns, so clearly it can't be done on the last column. The standard way of doing things is: only pool on even sized data. Change the size of your filters if needed.

Comment: This makes sense, but just as an aside, it differs from what is done in caffe.  As for changing the size of the filters, eventually there will be an odd numbered filter if 2d maxpooling is done (with 2x2 strides) for multiple layers (unless the original filter size is a power of 2).

Comment: Also, default pooling on a single column should return the column.  This can be done via the addition of an extraneous zero padding column...